# How to use phpmyadmin while creating development environment with wp-env?

Tags: wordpress, docker, phpmyadmin, phpunit

I am using wp-env to create development environment for my wordpress plugin.
Anybody knows a way to add phpmyadmin to the working container to access DB tables?

I have searched for any tutorial for this with no luck. also, using custom docker image may solve the issue but I faced another issues with testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its perhaps a bit late for you but I needed to do this to support an old WordPress project. Since I saw your question and also couldn't find any quick answers, I wrote a small script and published a gist to share:

https://gist.github.com/firxworx/cd114d55c9b5135f19bab51ba212c92b

Assuming that wp-env is running, the script implements the following recipe that answers your question:

- find the container name of the wordpress database created by wp-env using `docker ps` with `--filter` flag plus `grep`. The filter values are based on the fact wp-env uses the 'mariadb' image and includes 'mysql' in the generated container name. `grep` is used to exclude the 'tests-mysql' container from the result so only the 'mysql' container remains.
- find the network name of the database container in the results of `docker inspect <container_name>` by using the `jq` command to filter the json result: `jq -r '.[0].NetworkSettings.Networks | keys[]'`
- use the `docker run` command to pull and run the `phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest` docker image as a container with env vars set to connect to the database container via the docker network used by the wp-env containers on port `3306` with the default wp-env database credentials of `root` / `password`

The script will run phpmyadmin at http://localhost:8080.

It is easily adapted to connect to the 'tests-mysql' container instead if you need to do that.

If you don't have `jq` installed on your system it is a developer essential for working with json in scripts. It's available on every popular linux distro (e.g. Ubuntu: `sudo apt install -y jq`) and is on brew if you use MacOS (e.g. `brew install jq`).

Comment: Amazing. this is working for me perfectly. Thanks @firxworx.